Integrate Next app into PHP generated website
I have this Next JS 14 app which is basically a shopping cart. I build the app with output: 'export' in the next.config.mjs file. How can I add this to an existing website (PHP generated) so it doesn't mess up with it. I tried to include (or even echo the content of) the index.html which is generated by Next in the PHP website but as soon as the JS files are loaded, they take over the entire screen. (The existing PHP generated website has a sidebar and a navbar and I want the Next JS generated code to appear as the content).

Did you consider using an iframe ?

@halonico trying to avoid that approach.

Next.js main purpose is to provide server - side rendering for React applications (also static site generation, which is your case). That means that Next expects be in total control of page rendering, which is not what you're looking.
So, to add Next.js / React components to the page, which is rendered by PHP, I suggest following solutions:

Using iframe. This way you can granually insert Next.js pages into your application (however, Jay is trying to avoid this approach)
Migrate UI to Next.js completely. This way your pages are generated by Next.js and may communicate with PHP backend via API endpoints
Just use React without Next.js. You may use React to generate static and include it within your PHP application, like you did with Next static. If you have multiple pages (or just different components), you may create separate entry points in your webpack configuration for each page / component, and specify where to mount them using createRoot.

Also, if you're using another frontend frameworks to render the rest of the page (Angular, Vue, etc.), consider using micro frontend architecture.

Thanks Vladyslav . The third one got me going.
